# Is $A \cap \mathscr{P}(A) = \emptyset$ always true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

One of my problem set says $A \cap \mathscr{P}(A) = \emptyset$.

However if I take $A$ as:

Let $B = \{1\}$ and $A = \mathscr{P}(B) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$, then $\mathscr{P}(A) = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{1\}\}, \{\emptyset, \{1\}\}\}$

Now $A \cap \mathscr{P}(A) = \{\emptyset\} \neq \emptyset$.

Is there any thing wrong in my thinking here, or is it wrong to say that $A \cap \mathscr{P}(A) = \emptyset$ ?

Comment: Sometimes it is, and sometimes it isn't. In your example, $A \cap \mathscr{P}(A) = \{\emptyset\}\ne\emptyset$, but $B \cap \mathscr{P}(B) = \emptyset$. (And note that $\{1\}\notin\mathscr{P}(A)$ $-$ it should be $\{\{1\}\}$.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is a natural number equal or greater than $1$, say $A=2=\{0,1\}$.

One has :  $1\in A$ , and also $1\subseteq A$ because $0\in A$ ( implying that $\{0\}\subseteq A$).

Hence the intersection of $A$ and of the powerset of $A$ contains number $1$ as element ; this intersection is therefore not empty.

Note : in general , if natural number $n'$ is the successor of natural number $n$, then , by definition, $n'= n\cup \{n\}$

The moral of the story is  that, while membership and inclusion are two *distinct* relations, they are not incompatible nor contrary to one another.

Comment: In your example the $A \cap \mathscr{P}(A) =\emptyset$. Here, $\mathscr{P}(A) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$. $1 \notin \mathscr{P}(A)$.

Comment: @Floridus: Your post seems a bit random, i.e. it does not address the question (which has nothing to do with natural numbers, but with set theory in general).

Comment: I aimed at providing a counterexample to the alledged generel rule ( isn't that sound method?)

Comment: I think you're glossing over the point that $0=\varnothing$, and $1=\{0\}=\{\varnothing\}$. Not everyone knows that. And it's much clearer to just use $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ instead anyway.